# how to get rid of dual booting and only use ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I just installed Ubuntu from Wubi and it automatically made it dual boot but I want it to only boot from Ubuntu. I have not tried anything yet because I don't want to ruin my computer.

Comment: Dual boot does not ruin your PC

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

If you want to remove Windows and only have Ubuntu installed, you can't use Wubi. You need to create a bootable USB or DVD. This is pretty simple, and there are alot of online step-by-step tutorials to guide you safely through the process.

Quick guide using USB:

1. [Download unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and install your Ubuntu ISO file on the USB-drive.
2. Enter BIOS and set USB as 1st boot option
3. Plug in the USB and reboot
4. Choose "Install Ubuntu" when Ubuntu Live session is booted
5. Choose "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu"

[Official guide to install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Hope this helped answer your question!

Answer (score -1):

if you're running Ubuntu on the chromebook, open a terminal command prompt ((Ctrl+Alt+t) and type this command:

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sd
```

if you, for some reason, want to boot back into chrome os, type in the same command, but change the "5" after the "P" into a "0". Hope this helps!